# Prevent embedded form from scrolling to top of viewport?

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm embedding a Cognito Form (https://cognitoforms.com) on a web page with a sticky header that uses the first 190px of the viewport.  After the form is submitted, if there was an error (e.g. missing required field), the form reloads to show an error message.  And it also seems to a do a "scroll to top" thing, completely clueless there's a sticky header up there.  The form happily puts part of itself behind the header, where it can't be seen.

I tried several things involving adding some margin and/or padding to the top of the form.  But it's a 3rd-party embed that brings along its own javascript (which I suspect is firing the "scroll to top" thing) so I can't overwrite it.

Is there some way to tell an element on page, even if it's embedded from a 3rd-party site, to "stay where it is"?

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's parent has overflow:hidden